# No feasible entries for infix operator "-"

Tags: vhdl

I'm a beginner in VHDL.
Following is my code of a arithmetic extender (a part of my ALU design)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity arith_extd is port (
    m,s1,s0 : in std_logic; -- control signals
    A,B     : in std_logic; -- Full adder inputs
    O       : out std_logic -- Cout
);
end arith_extd; 

architecture logic_1 of arith_extd is
begin
    o <= ((A - 1) and (not m) and (not s0) and (not s1))
        or ((A + B) and (not m) and  s0 and (not s1))
        or ((A + (not B) + 1 )and (not m) and  (not s0 )and s1) 
        or ((A - 1) and (not m) and s0 and s1 );
end logic_1;
```

after compiling the following errors m coming across for the operators(+,-)and "and":

```
Error: F:/arith_ex.vhd(16): No feasible entries for infix operator "-".
Error: F:/arith_ex.vhd(16): Bad expression in left operand of infix expression "and"
Error: F:/arith_ex.vhd(18): Bad expression in left operand of infix expression "+".
```

Comment: It isn't clear what functions `s0` and `s1` select between.  If that was discernible from your question further help might be possible.  Type std_ulogic and derivative types (std_ulogic) don't have adding operators (e.g. `+`, `-`) defined for them, they are single 'bit' types with a multi value notational system, boolean operations on std_logic are performed with logical operators (e.g. `and`, `or`). Your question other than reporting errors lacks specificity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors just tell you that you perform operations that are not defined for the given types of the signals. For instance, there is no '-' (minus) operation defined on a single std_logic signal. VHDL is really strongly typed.

If you are about to describe an ALU, then I recommend to read the VHDL code of the [numeric_std library](http://www.eda-stds.org/vhdl-200x/vhdl-200x-ft/packages_old/numeric_std.vhdl). There you will understand how to juggle with std_logic_vectors, unsigned, signed etc.

Also [Doulos page](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/numeric_std/) is mandatory.